# Скрипт загрузки контента работает только с jquery-1.6.1,а с более новой не хочет

Tags: jquery

Это сам скрипт загрузки, нужно заставить его работать с более новыми версиями  jquery.

```
// Ajax-fetching "Load more posts"
$(function() {
$('.fetch a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('loading').text('Загружаем...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '#boxes',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(out) {
            result = $(out).find('#boxes .box');
            nextlink = $(out).find('.fetch a').attr('href');
            $('#boxes').append(result).masonry('appended', result);
            $('.fetch a').removeClass('loading').text('Больше статей');
            if (nextlink != undefined) {
                $('.fetch a').attr('href', nextlink);
            } else {
                $('.fetch').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: замени live на on

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))))

Answer (score 1):

После версии 1.9 необходимо переходить с live, на on.